# Reading .txt file content to DataTable with Column headers on first line

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I am trying to load data from a `.txt` file which looks like this:

```
|ABC|DEF|GHI|
|111|222|333|
|444|555|666|
```

With code:

```
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.Default).ReadToEnd()))
{
    string line;
    //reader.ReadLine(); //skip first line
    while (reader.Peek() != -1)
    {
        line = reader.ReadLine();
        if (line == null || line.Length == 0)
            continue;

        string[] values = line.Split('|').Skip(1).ToArray();

        if (!isColumnCreated)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Count(); i++)
            {
                table.Columns.Add(values[i]);
            }
            isColumnCreated = true;
        }

        DataRow row = table.NewRow();

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Count(); i++)
        {
            row[i] = values[i];
        }
        table.Rows.Add(row);
        products++;
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I generate a `DataTable`, I have first line as Column, but first line:

> |ABC|DEF|GHI|

is visible also in the rows:

[image]

How to put first line as column headers and rest as rows?

I do not want to use `CSVHelper` for that if it possible.

Comment: How are you saving it to database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to skip when the first line after header is created

```
string line;
bool bheader= false;
                    //reader.ReadLine(); //skip first line
                    while (reader.Peek() != -1)
                    {

                        line = reader.ReadLine();
                        if (line == null || line.Length == 0)
                            continue;

                        string[] values = line.Split('|').Skip(1).ToArray();


                        if (!isColumnCreated)
                        {

                            for (int i = 0; i < values.Count(); i++)
                            {
                                table.Columns.Add(values[i]);
                            }
                            isColumnCreated = true;
                            bheader = true;
                        }
if(bheader ==false){
                        DataRow row = table.NewRow();

                        for (int i = 0; i < values.Count(); i++)
                        {
                            row[i] = values[i];

                        }
                        table.Rows.Add(row);
                        products++;
                    }
                    }
                    bheader = false;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your current code is that you handle when isColumnCreated is false, but not true. If you change this:

```
                    if (!isColumnCreated)
                    {

                        for (int i = 0; i < values.Count(); i++)
                        {
                            table.Columns.Add(values[i]);
                        }
                        isColumnCreated = true;
                    }

                    DataRow row = table.NewRow();

                    for (int i = 0; i < values.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        row[i] = values[i];

                    }
                    table.Rows.Add(row);
                    products++;
```

to this

```
                    if (!isColumnCreated)
                    {

                        for (int i = 0; i < values.Count(); i++)
                        {
                            table.Columns.Add(values[i]);
                        }
                        isColumnCreated = true;
                    }

                    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                    else if (isColumnCreated)
                    {
                         for (int i = 0; i < values.Count(); i++)
                         {
                               row[i] = values[i];

                         }
                         table.Rows.Add(row);
                    }
```

it should work just fine. By only creating a row if the column headers have been created you're creating a situation wherein only on the first pass do you do anything with the first row, then it gets dumped.

Answer (score 0):

I would think you want to add the columns or add a row.

```
if (!isColumnCreated)
{

  for (int i = 0; i < values.Count(); i++)
  {
   table.Columns.Add(values[i]);
   }
   isColumnCreated = true;
   }
 }
else
{
  DataRow row = table.NewRow();

  for (int i = 0; i < values.Count(); i++)
  {
  row[i] = values[i];

  }
  table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("PathToFile"))
        {
            string currentline = string.Empty;
            bool doneHeader = false;
            while ((currentline = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (!doneHeader)
                {
                    foreach (string item in currentline.Split('YourDelimiter'))
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(item);
                    }
                    doneHeader = true;
                    continue;
                }
                dt.Rows.Add();
                int colCount = 0;
                foreach (string item in currentline.Split('YourDelimiter'))
                {
                    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][colCount] = item;
                    colCount++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method, more `LINQ` oriented.

> - Use [File.ReadAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) to parse all the File lines into a string array.
> - Create a `List<string[]>` containing all the data Rows.
>    The columns values are composed [splitting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.String.Split);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) the string row using a
>     provided `Delimiter`.
> - The first Row values are used to build a `DataTable` `Columns` elements.
> - The first Row is removed from the List.
> - All the other Rows are added to the `DataTable.Rows` collection.
> - Set a `DataGridView.DataSource` to the new `DataTable`.

```
char Delimiter = '|';
string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines("[SomeFilePath]", Encoding.Default);
List<string[]> FileRows = Lines.Select(line => 
    line.Split(new[] { Delimiter }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).ToList();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.AddRange(FileRows[0].Select(col => new DataColumn() { ColumnName = col }).ToArray());

FileRows.RemoveAt(0);
FileRows.ForEach(row => dt.Rows.Add(row));

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```